# No results for a query, but getting a number when turning into a subquery and making a count in redshift

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select count(*), cvc_date, cvc_product_id, cvc_seller_product_id, competitor_wid
from dw.f_catalogvscompetitors
group by cvc_date, cvc_product_id, cvc_seller_product_id, competitor_wid
having count(*) > 1
```

When I execute it, I get 0 rows as a result. However, when I make this:

```
select count(*) from (
select count(*), cvc_date, cvc_product_id, cvc_seller_product_id, competitor_wid
from dw.f_catalogvscompetitors
group by cvc_date, cvc_product_id, cvc_seller_product_id, competitor_wid
having count(*) > 1)
```

I get the number 22584. How is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible.  My guess is that the queries are subtly different -- perhaps referencing different databases or something.

Comment: They are exactly the same. I am adding the count over the first query, without modifying anything

Comment: can u replicate a data set on http://sqlfiddle.com/?